# Intl Polyfill + Next.js SSR application

Tags: webpack, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-intl

How can I polyfill intl on a Next.js application? Some Chinese browsers still don't have it, and we use react-intl, which requires Intl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### polyfills in Next.js (in general)

Next.js has some examples for polyfills in general:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-polyfills

Next.js recommends to import the needed polyfill(s) inside the `<App>` component, or in the individual component that uses the polyfill(s).

E.g.:

```
// /pages/_app.js

import 'polyfill_some_feature';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }){
  return <Component { ...pageProps } />
}

export default MyApp
```

#### polyfills for the `Intl` API

[formatjs / react-intl](https://formatjs.io/docs/getting-started/installation/) provides some [polyfills](https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/) for the `Intl` API.

The features that you need, like `Intl.getCanonicalLocales`, `Intl.Locale`, `Intl.PluralRules`, ..., have to be imported seperately.

Note that the polyfills depend on each other, so the order in which they are called matters.
E.g. the polyfill for `Intl.getCanonicalLocales` checks if `typeof Intl === 'undefined'`, but the polyfill for `Intl.Locale` relies on the existence of `Intl` already.

Here is one of their examples (this one is for implementing `getCanonicalLocales`):
https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-getcanonicallocales/#dynamic-import--capability-detection

```
npm i @formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales
```

```
import { shouldPolyfill } from '@formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales/should-polyfill';

async function polyfill() {
  if( shouldPolyfill() ){
    await import('@formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales/polyfill');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [custom express server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) in order to apply the Intl polyfill.